# Proof of Hoffman & Kruskal's theorem on Unimodularity and Integrality.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming, unimodular-matrices

I'm reading the following proof.

> **Thm. (Unimodularity and Integrality, Hoffman & Kruskal [1956]):**
> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \operatorname{rank} A=n .$ The following are equivalent:
> a) $A$ is unimodular
> b) $\operatorname{vert}(P(A, b)) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^{n}, \forall b \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}$, where $P(A,b)$ is the polyhedron associated with the system $Ax \leq b$.
> c) $A_{I.}^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}, \forall$ regular $A_{I} . \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ (The notation $A_{I.}$ denotes the submatrix of $A$, comprised of the rows $I$ of $A$, for a set of indices $I$.)

> **Proof:**
> **b) $\Rightarrow$ c):**
> Let $A_{I}$. be regular, w.l.o.g. $I=[n], J=[m] \backslash[n]$.
> Let
> $x^{i}:=\left(A_{I}^{-1}\right)_{\cdot i}$ be the $i$-th column of $A_{I}^{-1}$, and
> $b^{i}:=A x^{i}=\left(\begin{array}{c} e_{i} \\ A_{J} \cdot x^{i} \end{array}\right), i \in I \\$
> $\Rightarrow  x^{i} \in \operatorname{vert} P(A, b), i \in I \\
> \Rightarrow  x^{i} \text { integer, } i \in I \\
> \Rightarrow  A_{I.}^{-1} \text{ integer. }$

I assume in "$x^{i} \in \operatorname{vert} P(A, b), i \in I$", the author means the $b^i$ as defined in the previously, instead of just some general $b$? But if so, how do we make sure that the lower entries of $b^i$ are also integer, so that we can apply the second condition in the theorem?

Comment: What is the meaning of "vert" and "P" in "vert(P,...)" ? Same question for $A_I$ : is $I$ a set of indices ? Can you give a web reference ?

Comment: I've just made an edit. Hopefully it's clearer.

Comment: And yes, $I$ is a set of indices. $A_{I.}$ is the submatrix of $A$, comprised of the rows $I$ of $A$.

Comment: Do you mean modular or Totally Unimodular (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix) ?

Comment: Besides, can you confirm that the sets $I$ have cardinality $n$ ?

Comment: In the context of the document I'm reading, the unimodularity criterion applies to the maximal square submatrices, while the totally unimodularity criterion applies to all square submatrices. And yes, we have $|I| = n$ (and $I = [n]$) in the theorem and proof above. I'm sorry for the confusion and the inconsistencies of terminologies.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/kruskalhoffman.pdf) the (original) document you are reading ?